# Is there a way to perform dex/smali/android class verification on linux or mac?

Tags: android

Is there a way to perform class verification on dex or smali files before the apk is pushed to the android device?

Comment: This is a good question but unfortunately doesn't seem like a good RE question. There are other forums on software development that may be able to better answer your question.

Answer (score 3):

The only way I'm aware of is to build art for the host and load/run the dex file with that. I don't have specific steps/info handy, but the android build process normally builds a host build of art, for dex pre-oating, and you should be able to use that to verify your dex file.